# How to bulk ASC files into GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, ascii

I am trying to import some LiDAR files (.asc) into a binary raster map layer using the r.in.gdal module from GRASS.

As I have multiple files to import, I would like to batch import them.
It is possible or should do I have to repeat the same operation for every single file?
I know that r.import can bulk raster files like GeoTIFF but does not work with .asc files.

I work with GRASS 7.8.2

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what exactly does not work? what is the error

Comment: There are not error if i import the files one by one. I am trying to bulk the 46 files in the same time. I don't find how.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues here:

1. If your LiDAR data are in *.asc format, that typically means that it's point data (not raster). So you do not want to use `r.in.gdal`. You would need to import as points, possible using `v.in.ascii`, then interpolate an elevation grid. THis can be done with `v.surf.rst`.
2. Additionally, sometimes *.asc are point data **on a regular grid** i.e. evenly spaced x and y coordinates. If that's the case, then you can import to GRASS with `r.in.xyz`.
3. There is a raster format, ArcINFO ASCII, which is indeed a raster format, and the extension might be *.asc. If that's the case, then `r.in.gdal` or `r.import` should work.

LiDAR data are usually *.las or *.laz. So, in order to give a proper answer, we need to know what these "LiDAR files (.asc)" actually are.

Comment: `asc` files are usually ASCII grid files and are rasters, but converting them to a GeoTiff using `gdal_translate` will usually make your life easier

Comment: The problem not is to import. I have import the files (Raster files) using r.in.gdal or r.import. There are .asc files. My question not is how import a single file. My question is how to bulk many files at same time.

Comment: Typically this would be done with a loop. If you're on Linux, a `for` loop in bash would be appropriate. On windows, it's similar, but with a slightly different format. Python is also a good choice.

What programming tools are you comfortable with?